# MS Excel: Run-time error '1004' No cells were found

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have the following vba code:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F1")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:F4")

rng1.Copy rng2 //throws the runtime exception.
```

Whereas column 'C' is hidden and have applied filter on column 'B' based on value.

I am getting "Run-time error '1004': No cells were found." at `rng1.Copy rng2`. This error is particularly thrown when the SpecialCells returns no cells but here I am not using it.

If I remove the filter applied on column 'B', it works fine. I am not getting why filter is failing the copy and paste operation.

Any help or suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Fourth row is not hidden, it's visible. Yeah I need the format of the range to be copied

Comment: Strange... Are there any sheet protection in place? Are there any merge cells on that range? Even if the error should be different... Even if your code is not incorrect, please, try `Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")`.

Comment: Are you sure that the active workbook is the one you try processing...?

Comment: Yeah it's active workbook. Your code snippet is not throwing error but formats are copied one column less from Column 'D' i.e. E1 to D4, F1 to E4 as  Column 'C' is hidden. Btw, No formats are applied to Column 'C'.

Comment: So, you did not tell us all the truth... Besides the filter, which hides rows, not bothering the code, you have a hidden column in between. I am afraid that you must unhide (in code) that column, copy what you need and hide it after...

Comment: I've already mentioned it in the post, please check

Comment: Ups... You are right. I missed it.